# jquery not working on ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a multiple checkboxs loaded from another file by ajax with class 'chk-bx'

```
<script>

$('.chk-bx').on( "click", function(){

   alert("checked");
   });

</script>
```

There are some checkboxes that are there beore loading ajax then its working fine. but after loading its not working.

Thanks you verymuch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handler is initialized before the checkboxes get to the DOM. You have to initialize the handler on the new checkboxes after they appeared in the DOM.

Edit: As Rory said, you can use a delegated event handler. You can attach the handler to a common parent of your checkboxes, like `$( "#checkbox-container" ).on( "click", ".chk-bx", function() {...})`. That way the newly added checkboxes in the `#checkbox-container` element will have that listener ran on a click event. You can read more about it here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Or even simpler, use a single delegated event handler on all of them.

Comment: Yes, that's right, that makes it simpler, I add that to the answer